# how can i make list tag box clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css

Right now anchor tag is working when i click on text, how can i make circle clickable too.

i tried to put `<a> </a>` tag outside of list tag but it's not working that way too,

What i want is whether i click on text (step1-step5) or circle it should open relevant link.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mattii/z5de0Ljs/228/)

```
<div class="timeline-wrapper">
      <ul class="StepProgress">
        <li onclick="setSelected(this)" class="StepProgress-item is-done">
    
          <div class="bold"><a href="www.google.com">Step 1 </a></div>
        </li>
        <li onclick="setSelected(this)" class="StepProgress-item current">
    
          <div class="bold"><a href="www.google.com">Step 2 </a></div>
    
        </li>
        <li onclick="setSelected(this)" class="StepProgress-item">
    
          <div class="bold"><a href="www.google.com">Step 3 </a> </div>
        </li>
        <li onclick="setSelected(this)" class="StepProgress-item">
    
          <div class="bold"><a href="www.google.com">Step 4 </a></div>
        </li>
        <li onclick="setSelected(this)" class="StepProgress-item">
    
          <div class="bold"><a href="www.google.com">Step 5 </a></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Javascript of the file;

**JS:**

```
 function setSelected(e) {
      const list = document.querySelector(".StepProgress");
      
      Object.values(list.childNodes).forEach((it, i) => {
        if (it.classList instanceof DOMTokenList) {
          if (it.classList.contains("is-done"))
            it.classList.remove("is-done");
        }
        
        if(it === e) {
          it.classList.add("is-done");
        }
      });
    }
```

CSS of the file,

**CSS:**

```
.bold {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .time {
      position: absolute;
      left: -110px;
    }
    
    .timeline-wrapper {
      padding-left: 80px;
      min-width: 400px;
      font-family: 'Helvetica';
      font-size: 14px;
      /*border: 1px solid #CCC;*/
    }
    
    .StepProgress {
      position: relative;
      padding-left: 45px;
      list-style: none;
    }   
    .StepProgress::before {
      display: inline-block;
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 15px;
      width: 10px;
      height: 100%;
      border-left: 2px solid #CCC;
    }
    
    .StepProgress-item {
      position: relative;
      counter-increment: list;
    }
    
    .StepProgress-item:not(:last-child) {
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    .StepProgress-item::before {
      display: inline-block;
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      left: -30px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 10px;
    }
    
    .StepProgress-item::after {
      content: '';
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: -37px;
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      border: 2px solid #CCC;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: #FFF;
    }
    
    .StepProgress-item.is-done::after {
      /*content: "?";*/
      font-size: 10px;
      color: #FFF;
      text-align: center;
      border: 2px solid green;
      background-color: green;
    }
    
    .StepProgress strong {
      display: block;
    }
```

Comment: Make that circle as a `div` in HTML instead of using CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You achieve this by adding this line which select the anchor inside the current element and trigger the click event

```
if(it === e) {
  it.classList.add("is-done");
  it.querySelector('a').click()
}
```

Comment: clever end elegant